# How to pass a 2d vector using pass-by-reference?

Tags: c++, xcode, vector, 2d, pass-by-reference

this code is a part of a larger project. I am trying to understand how to pass a 2d vector to another function by using a reference. This is my current code, and I cannot figure out what the error is (using Xcode).

The Code:

```
int main()
{
   int mines, col, row;

   int test;

   cout << "\nHow many many rows of boxes?" <<endl; //getting row, 
   //column and mines from user

   cin >> row;
   cout << "\nHow many many columns of boxes?" <<endl;
   cin >> col;
   cout << "\nHow many many mines are in the board?" <<endl;
   cin >> mines;

   test=(row*col)-1;        // test to make sure that the whole gameboard is not filled with mines (multiplies row and columns and subtracts by 1)
   while (!(test>= mines))  // if there are more mines than cells or if the whole board is filled with mines, will ask for mines again
   {
      cout << "\nHow many many mines are in the board?" <<endl;
      cin >> mines;
   }

   vector <vector<int> > grid(col, vector<int>(row));   //create 2d vector with col and row as parameters

   minesweeper(row, col, mines, vector< vector<int> > grid(col, vector<int>(row)))  //sends all data to minesweeper();




   return 0;
}

void minesweeper(int row,
                 int col,
                 int numOfMines,
                 vector<vector<int>>& mineField)
{
}
```

EDIT:

Sorry, I totally botched the question. It was late night and I forgot to copy the headers and the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This is garbled C++ syntax. in the call to minesweeper, you're attempting to declare and initialize a variable called grid. What? You already have a variable called grid. Just get a C++ textbook and type `grid` instead of `vector< vector<int> > grid(col, vector<int>(row))` so you have

```
vector <vector<int> > grid(col, vector<int>(row));  //create 2d vector with col and row as parameters

minesweeper(row, col, mines,  grid);
```

After that it's being passed by reference because you have declared the parameter specially to make it by reference. Do you see anything different on the mineField parameter than on the other parameters that would make it specially flagged as passing by reference?

and consider naming a variable describing the number of rows as `rows` instead of `row`.

Answer (score 0):

Problems I see:

1. You have not declared the function `minesweeper` before calling it. Add a declaration before `main`.

   ```
   void minesweeper(int row,
                    int col,
                    int numOfMines,
                    vector<vector<int>>& mineField);
   ```
2. You are not using the right syntax for calling the function. Use:

   ```
   minesweeper(row, col, mines, grid)  //sends all data to minesweeper();
   ```

   You have already declared `grid` before that line. You can use it after that. There is no need to add the code used to declare `grid` in the call to `minesweeper`.